# Java: How to check a Credit Cards validity using the Luhn check and using Methods

Tags: java, methods, luhn

I've been trying to figure out this Luhns method of validating a Credit Card but I can't seem to figure it out. I NEED to use methods and cannot use arrays so I'm totally stumped.

Here's the Luhns check:

A credit card number must have between 13 and 16 digits. It must start with:
■ 4 for Visa cards
■ 5 for Master cards
■ 37 for American Express cards
■ 6 for Discover cards

1. Double every second digit from right to left. If doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add up the two digits to get a single-digit number.
2. Now add all single-digit numbers from Step a.
3. Add all digits in the odd places from right to left in the card number.
4. Sum the results from Step b and Step c.
5. If the result from Step d is divisible by 10, the card number is valid; otherwise, it is invalid. For example, the number 4388576018402626 is invalid, but the number 4388576018410707 is valid.

My issue is that I'm still learning methods (Total beginner. I tried to learn to code once last year and gave up, but I've managed to get this far this time) and I can't figure out how to use these methods to both do step 4 and 5 from the Luhn check.

Could someone please try to help me out? Thank you!!

```
public static boolean isValid(String x) {
    return false; // Stub method    
}

public static void AddResults() {

}

public static void OddDigits(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < s.length(); index ++) {
        if (index % 2 != 0) {
            sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(index));
        }
    }
    return;
}

public static int DoubleToSingle(int x) { // Adds up the digits in a two-digit number. 
    if (x < 10) {
        return x;
    } 
    else {
        int firstDigit = x % 10;
        int secondDigit = (int)(x / 10);
        return firstDigit + secondDigit;
    }
}

public static void Doubling(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = s.length() - 1; index > 0; index-= 2) {
        int parse = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(index));
        if (parse > 9) {
        sum = sum + DoubleToSingle(parse);
        }
        else {
            sum = sum + parse;
        }
    }

    return;
}

public static boolean CheckLength(String s) {
    if (s.length() < 13 || s.length() > 16) { // If the cc number is smaller than 13 digits or larger than 16 digits, it's invalid
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static String ReadString(Scanner s) { // Creating a string method. (Using it to practice creating methods)
    String x = s.nextLine();
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input a valid Credit Card number: ");
    String CC = ReadString(input);

    if (isValid(CC) == true) {
        System.out.println(CC + " is valid.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(CC + " is invalid.");
    }       
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

Comments about your code:

- Java naming convention is for method names to start with lowercase letter, like your  `isValid` method.
- In the `doubleToSingle` method, `x` is an `int`, and `10` is an `int` literal, so `x / 10` will be an `int`, with the result truncated, which means there is no need for this cast: `(int)(x / 10)`
- Since `doubleToSingle` method can handle single-digit numbers, there is no need for the caller (`doubling` method) to handle it too, so eliminate the `if (parse > 9)` test.
- Counting digits *from the right* works like this:

  ```
   5th digit       Odd places:
   ↓ 3rd digit       Don't double these digits, just sum them
   ↓ ↓ 1st digit
   ↓ ↓ ↓
  999999
  ↑ ↑ ↑
  ↑ ↑ 2nd digit    Even places, aka "every second digit from right":
  ↑ 4th digit        Double these digits, combine digits when
  6th digit          two-digit number, then sum them
  ```

  The `doubling` method starts at the *last* index, not the second-last as it should, and it skips the *first* index, which it shouldn't. The loop should be:

  ```
  for (int index = s.length() - 2; index >= 0; index -= 2)
  ```
- The `doubling` method do need to actually *double* the number (`parse * 2`) before calling the `doubleToSingle` method.
- The `oddDigits` method counts odd/even from the *left*, when it should count from the *right*.

  Remove the `if (index % 2 != 0)` test, and use similar loop as used in `doubling` method:

  ```
  for (int index = s.length() - 1; index >= 0; index -= 2)
  ```
- The `doubling` and `oddDigits` methods should `return` the `sum`, otherwise what's the point?

If think the lack of return value from the `doubling` and `oddDigits` methods is what got you stuck, so I'll let you work on the rest of your code from here.

---

Although the following code is beyond your current skill level, I want to show it so you have something to look forward to, being able to understand and eventually write code like it.

```
public static boolean isValid(String cc) {
    if (! cc.matches("(?=[456]|37)[0-9]{13,16}"))
        return false;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = cc.length() - 1, pos = 1; i >= 0; i--, pos++) {
        int digit = cc.charAt(i) - '0';
        sum += (pos % 2 == 1/*odd*/ ? digit : digit < 5 ? digit * 2 : digit * 2 - 9);
    }
    return (sum % 10 == 0);
}
```

It tests all the conditions listed in the question, even the "It must start with" part that you haven't started on yet. At your skill level, you should probably use `s.startsWith("xx")` instead of the `matches(...)` regular expression used here.